# What am I doing wrong with this Scheme evaluation?

Tags: lambda, scheme, evaluation

Evaluate:

```
((((lambda (x) (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y)))) 3) 4) 5)
```

This is what I did:

- evaluate `((((lambda (x) (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y)))) 3) 4) 5)`

  - evaluate `5 -> 5`
- evaluate `(((lambda (x) (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y)))) 3) 4)`

  - evaluate `4 -> 4`
- evaluate `((lambda (x) (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y)))) 3)`

  - evaluate `3 -> 3`
- `(lambda (x) (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y))))` -> `(lambda (x) (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y))))`
- apply `(lambda (x) (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y))))` to `3`

  - substitute `3` -> `x` in `(lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y))`
  - `(lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ 3 y))`
  - evaluate `(lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ 3 y)) -> (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ 3 y))`
  - `apply (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ 3 y))` to `4`
  - subsitute `4 -> y` in `(lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ 3 y))`
  - `(lambda (y)  (+ 3 4))`
  - evaluate `(lambda (y)  (+ 3 4)) -> (lambda (y)  (7))`

    - subsitute `5` -> ?

And then I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you break this down into individual 'defined' procedures.

```
(define part1 (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y)))) ; basically an adder
(define part2 (lambda (x) part1))  ; just return part1, x has no effect
```

Now call `(((part2 3) 4) 5) => 9`

Answer (score 1):

```
-substitute 3 -> x in (lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y))
-(lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ 3 y))
```

First, this is wrong.  You don't substitute `3` for all occurrences of `x`, only for the free ones.  The `x` you're replacing here is bound by the inner lambda expression and therefore not free.

Second, there's nothing wrong with substituting a value for a variable that's never used, so substituting `5` for `y` in `(+ 3 4)` is fine and yields `(+ 3 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first substitution is wrong; the `x` in `(+ x y)` is bound by the innermost `lambda`, not the outermost. This means the result of that substitution is just `(lambda (y) (lambda (x) (+ x y)))`. The `3` is "lost". (Perhaps you should look up the substitution rules and apply them step by step to getter a better grasp of it.)

Regardless of this, to finish you can still apply `(lambda (y) (7))` (or `(lambda (y) (+ 4 x))` if you fix the above) to `5` to get `7` (or `(+ 4 5)` which evaluates to `9`).